# Change the default number of rows in griddle

Tags: reactjs, griddler

I'm trying to change the default number of rows displaying in the griddle. Does anybody know how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is simple. Just use "**resultsPerPage**" property in Griddle Tag. In the following below I display 3 rows only instead of 5 default rows per page.

```
<Griddle resultsPerPage={3} results={fakeData}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should definitely be made into a pull request for added functionality, but the line that sets the default is [https://github.com/GriddleGriddle/Griddle/blob/master/scripts/griddle.jsx#L37] and you could change it manually.